# Python 3: tokenize library changes

Tags: python, python-3.x, compatibility, tokenize

According to this: http://code.activestate.com/lists/python-list/413540/, `tokenize.generate_tokens` should be used and not `tokenize.tokenize`.

This works perfectly fine in `Python 2.6`. But it does not work anymore in `Python 3`:

```
>>> a = list(tokenize.generate_tokens(io.BytesIO("1\n".encode()).readline))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tokenize.py", line 439, in _tokenize
    if line[pos] in '#\r\n':           # skip comments or blank lines
```

However, also in `Python 3`, this works (and returns also the desired output):

```
a = list(tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO("1\n".encode()).readline))
```

According to the documentation, it seems like `tokenize.tokenize` is the new way to use this module: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/tokenize.html. `tokenize.generate_tokens` isn't even documented anymore.

But, why is there still a `generate_tokens` function in this module, if it's not documented?  I haven't found any PEP regarding this.

I'm trying to maintain a code base for `Python 2.5-3.2`, should I call `generate_tokens` for `Python 2` and `tokenize` for `Python 3`? Aren't there any better ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`generate_tokens` seems to be really a strange thing in `Python 3`. It doesn't work like in `Python 2`. However, `tokenize.tokenize` behaves like the old `Python 2` `tokenize.generate_tokens`. Therefore I wrote a little workaround:

```
import tokenize                             
if sys.hexversion >= 0x03000000d:                               
    tokenize_func = tokenize.tokenize       
else:                                       
    tokenize_func = tokenize.generate_tokens
```

Now I just use `tokenize_func`, which works without problems.

Answer (score 0):

`generate_tokens` in python3 is undocumented but [not uncommented](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/tokenize.py#l531). it's there for backward compatibility, so you can use it, but it's probably better to use the changed [`tokenize`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.2/Lib/tokenize.py#l354) instead...

Comment: More specifically, `tokenize()` in Python 3 expects file-like objects in bytes mode. `generate_tokens` is left for using objects in text mode (i.e. reading unicode).